# How to make a login system that stores levels in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So I want to make a game that allows saving your level progress by entering your username. But I need to be able to store multiple users and retrieve that value again.

So far, I have made:

```
import json
username = input("Enter your username ")
try:
  with open('users.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for text in data['users']:
      if text["username"].lower() == username.lower():
        level = text["level"]
        coins = text["coins"]
        print("Progress Restored")
except:
  level = 1
  coins = 10
  a = {"username": username
       "level": level
       "coins": coins
  }
```

And then I don't really know how to add on the code from there. Could someone help me, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can dump Json to a file like this:

```
with open('users.txt', 'w') as the_file:
    json.dump(a, the_file)
```